# Pandas from Django Aggregate Query

Tags: django, pandas

How do I convert aggregate qs into a DataFrame?

```
for i in a:
    qs = Cashflow.objects.filter ( acct = i.id ).aggregate(Min('month'), Max('month'), Avg('value'), Count('month'))

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ( qs )
```

I get this error:

```
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you add a `print(qs)` in the line right after `qs = ...` and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to do what I needed.

```
for i in accounts:

    qs = Cashflow.objects.filter ( id = i.id ).aggregate(Min('month'), Max('month'), Avg('value'), Count('month'))

    temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict ( [qs] )

    temp [ 'id' ] = i.id
    temp = temp.set_index ( 'id' )

    df = df.append ( temp )

df = df.reset_index()
```

results:

```
     id  month__count  month__max  month__min     value__avg
0    11            34  2016-04-30  2013-07-31         326329
1    32            19  2016-04-30  2014-10-31         258317
```

maybe there is a better way?

I hope this helps.